# Rails: gender and size attributes for marketplace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, attr, marketplace

I'm on my way to create a t-shirt marketplace, but I have a little problem which I don't know whats the best way to resolve.

obs: I'm using mongoId as database!

I have my `Order` model. It has several attributes and everything's ok, but I don't know how to define my `size` and my `gender` attr, because they are few constant options. For example: `size` can only have 5 different values: S, M, L, XL and XG.

Some people say I should use Hashes to store that data, some people say I should use Array Constants. Either way I haven't found a good way to show those options on my `form_for`.

Can you help me? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

If `Order` is the appropriate object to store sizes on, I would probably use an array constant. That would allow you to pass `Order::VALID_SIZES` as options in a select element in your form, and can also be used in a validation on the size:

```
class Order
  VALID_SIZES = %w[S M L XL XG]
  validates :size, inclusion: { in: VALID_SIZES }
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think thats what I was looking for! Do you know how can i reference that in a form_for#select_tag field, for example?